# Developing a Component or Creating It`

Tags: javascript, php, components, frontend

I found myself in the following situation. I'm developing a website or extension or other type of PHP product and I need some Javascript functionality.

I then have 3 choices to implement it:

1. Using a already existing plugin via GitHub
2. Develop a plugin myself and give back to the community
3. Develop the functionality but not in a plugin (smallest possible version)

The problem i have with using a plugin via github, is that I find it hard to assess if I should use it. How can I add functionality. The problem with option 2 is that it adds another 'project' to maintain.

How do you guys solve these issues ? How do you select approaches on which criteria ?

kind regards,

Comment: As a developer, I think your question is very good. But, it's probably that will receive many based opinion answers, which is bad by Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: I suggest you to use ready-to-use plugin. Don't create a bicycle. You can always fork selected plugin and modify it with you requirements